# Celery Task the difference between these two tasks below

Tags: django, django-celery

What's the difference between these two tasks below?

The first one gives an error, the second one runs just fine. Both are the same, they accept extra arguments and they are both called in the same way.

```
ProcessRequests.delay(batch) **error object.__new__() takes no parameters**


SendMessage.delay(message.pk, self.pk) **works!!!!**
```

Now, I have been made aware of what the error means, but my confusion is why one works and not the other.

Tasks...

**1)**

```
class ProcessRequests(Task):
    name = "Request to Process"
    max_retries = 1
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, batch):
       #do something
```

**2)**

```
class SendMessage(Task):
    name = "Sending SMS"
    max_retries = 10
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, message_id, gateway_id=None, **kwargs):
        #do something
```

Full Task Code....

```
from celery.task import Task
from celery.decorators import task

import logging

from sms.models import Message, Gateway, Batch
from contacts.models import Contact
from accounts.models import Transaction, Account


class SendMessage(Task):
    name = "Sending SMS"
    max_retries = 10
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, message_id, gateway_id=None, **kwargs):
        logging.debug("About to send a message.")

        # Because we don't always have control over transactions
        # in our calling code, we will retry up to 10 times, every 3
        # seconds, in order to try to allow for the commit to the database
        # to finish. That gives the server 30 seconds to write all of
        # the data to the database, and finish the view.
        try:
            message = Message.objects.get(pk=message_id)
        except Exception as exc:
            raise SendMessage.retry(exc=exc)


        if not gateway_id:
            if hasattr(message.billee, 'sms_gateway'):
                gateway = message.billee.sms_gateway
            else:
                gateway = Gateway.objects.all()[0]
        else:
            gateway = Gateway.objects.get(pk=gateway_id)

        # Check we have a credits to sent me message
        account = Account.objects.get(user=message.sender)
        # I'm getting the non-cathed version here, check performance!!!!!
        if account._balance() >= message.length:
            response = gateway._send(message)

            if response.status == 'Sent':
                # Take credit from users account.
                transaction = Transaction(
                    account=account,
                    amount=- message.charge,
                    description="Debit: SMS Sent",

                    )
                transaction.save()
                message.billed = True
                message.save()
        else:
            pass


        logging.debug("Done sending message.")


class ProcessRequests(Task):
    name = "Request to Process"
    max_retries = 1
    default_retry_delay = 3

    def run(self, message_batch):
        for e in Contact.objects.filter(contact_owner=message_batch.user, group=message_batch.group):
            msg = Message.objects.create(
                recipient_number=e.mobile,
                content=message_batch.content,
                sender=e.contact_owner,
                billee=message_batch.user,
                sender_name=message_batch.sender_name
            )
            gateway = Gateway.objects.get(pk=2)
            msg.send(gateway)
            #replace('[FIRSTNAME]', e.first_name)
```

tried:

```
 ProcessRequests.delay(batch) should work gives error error object.__new__() takes no parameters     
 ProcessRequests().delay(batch) also gives error error object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

Comment: How is `run()` implemented apart from the function signature?

Comment: Did you mean `ProcessRequests().delay(batch)`? Otherwise there is nothing wrong with the code in your post, it runs ok on my end. As was suggested, show us `run` bodies.

Comment: Yes is the one that gives me this error.  ProcessRequests().delay(batch) or ProcessRequest.delay(batch) does not work either

Comment: I have updated the question with the full code ProcessRequests is the one what will not run.

Comment: @gatto thats my issue I don't understand as this 'should work' nothing wrong with the code

Comment: the only way i have had it working was with ProcessRequests().run(batch)  but this is NOT the correct way as celery states

Comment: What `celery` version do you use? `Task.delay` is not a staticmethod, how can `SendMessage.delay` even work? It might be some obscure problem with module caching and whatnot. I'd try to make simple app with both tasks from scratch to see if the problem in this code or somewhere else.

Comment: "Correct" way is to use `celery.task` decorator for simple functions, and then run them as  `func.delay()`.

Comment: tired that too i.e. process_sms.delay(batch) using @task with the class and got 'function' object has no attribute 'delay'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue:

```
import celery
from celery.task import Task

@celery.task
class Foo(celery.Task):
    name = "foo"
    def run(self, batch):
       print 'Foo'

class Bar(celery.Task):
    name = "bar"
    def run(self, batch):
       print 'Bar'

# subclass deprecated base Task class
class Bar2(Task):
    name = "bar2"
    def run(self, batch):
       print 'Bar2'

@celery.task(name='def-foo')
def foo(batch):
    print 'foo'
```

Output:

```
In [2]: foo.delay('x')
[WARNING/PoolWorker-4] foo

In [3]: Foo().delay('x')
[WARNING/PoolWorker-2] Foo

In [4]: Bar().delay('x')
[WARNING/PoolWorker-3] Bar

In [5]: Foo.delay('x')
TypeError: object.__new__() takes no parameters

In [6]: Bar.delay('x')
TypeError: unbound method delay() must be called with Bar instance as first argument (got str instance instead)

In [7]: Bar2.delay('x')
[WARNING/PoolWorker-1] Bar2
```

I see you use deprecated `celery.task.Task` base class, this is why you don't get `unbound method` errors:

```
Definition: Task(self, *args, **kwargs)
Docstring:
Deprecated Task base class.

Modern applications should use :class:`celery.Task` instead.
```

I don't know why `ProcessRequests` doesn't work though. Maybe it is some caching issues, you may have tried to apply the decorator to your class before and it got cached, and this is exactly the error that you get when you try to apply this decorator to a Task class.

Delete all .pyc file, restart celery workers and try again.

**Don't use classes directly**

1. [Tasks are instantiated only once per (worker) process](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#instantiation), so creating objects of task classes (on client-side) every time doesn't make sense, i.e. `Bar()` is wrong.
2. `Foo.delay()` or `Foo().delay()` might or might not work, depends on combination of decorator `name` argument and class `name` attribute.

Get the task object from `celery.registry.tasks` dictionary or just use `@celery.task` decorator on functions (`foo` in my example) instead.

Comment: @User7: You can specify base classes for task functions, read from [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#custom-task-classes). In your case options you use may be passed to the decorator directly, without need for custom task classes.

Comment: I have a class that is defined just like `Foo`, but when I run it - `Foo().apply_async(args=[x])` I get the error - `TypeError: run() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`, and that is driving me crazy. Can't get it to work with the new style API - works just fine with the old style api. Can you help me out?

Comment: that is pretty much what I do. See this question I posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608915/problems-with-the-new-style-celery-api