# Problems with the new style celery api

Tags: python, celery

I have a class that extends celerys `Task`. It runs just fine with the old style API, but I am having problems converting it to the new API.

```
# In app/tasks.py
from celery import Celery, Task

celery = Celery()

@celery.task
class CustomTask(Task):

    def run(self, x):
        try:
            # do something
        except Exception, e:
            self.retry(args=[x], exc=e)
```

And then I run the task like so -

```
CustomTask().apply_async(args=[x], queue='q1')
```

And I get the error -

```
TypeError: run() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16218702/805427) seems to do the same thing and it was accepted so presumably it works. Can anyone help me out and explain to me why my code isn't working?

**EDIT**

This works if I name the task, different from the class name -

```
name = 'app.tasks.CustomTask2'
```

But if I keep the name of the task the same as the full class name, it doesn't work

```
name = 'app.tasks.CustomTask'
```

But the problem with having a different name is that celery has an extra task, with the same name as the task class name.

Comment: Why do you need `celery = Celery()`? Hm, nevermind, it's in the docs, although it doesn't work with it. Use functions, they work this way.

Comment: I don't. I was trying this out in the hope it might work when I posted this. I have tried it without `celery = Celery()` and it still gives the same error.

Comment: That is was using `import celery`, `@celery.task` and `celery.Task`

Comment: Hm, your example should work with `CustomTask.apply_async(...)`. [See](https://gist.github.com/anongit/000b341c1c73680bc0b7) my experiments on the subject.  This is an odd behaviour, I just assume that using classes like this is not the right way to go, i.e. you should you use functions maybe with custom base classes.

Comment: Weirdly, it worked when I changed the name of the task, both in the task class and in `routers.py`. But the old task still shows up when I start celery.

Comment: Another oddity - I get this error when the name of the class and the task are the same.

Comment: So I get this error when I have the task name same as the class name - `app.tasks.CustomTask`, and if I have different names, I get an extra task.

Comment: And it goes away when I stop using the decorator o.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decorator is not used with classes, it's used for functions.

Usually you will not want to define custom task classes unless you want to implement common behavior.

So either remove the `@celery.task` decorator, or use it with a function.

Note that the task you define here is not bound with any celery instance

Note bound to any specific app instance:

```
from celery import Task

class MyTask(Task):
    pass
```

You can bind it later:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(broker='amqp://')

MyTask.bind(app)
```

or you can use the base class available on the app:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery(broker='amqp://')

class MyTask(app.Task):
    pass
```

The last example is not very clean as it means you are finalizing the app at module level,
this is another reason why using the task decorator with functions is a best practice, and only create custom classes to be used as a base class for decorated tasks (`@task(base=MyTask)`).